# Rails3 -- Is there a way to tell if a hash link (internal link) has been used?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a client who wants a page to have their terms of service hidden at the bottom of a page with the following criteria:

1) on normal page load, the tos should be hidden with a js trigger next to the title to toggle the display
2) if an internal link was clicked, either a)from the current page or b)from an external page, the tos should show

For #1 and #2a (clicking on internal link from said page), no problem.
It is for #2b, when a user is coming from another page with #tos in the url, that I don't know how to detect the presence of #tos.

So, if UserA is on page /foo and clicks on a link to /bar#tos, how can I tell when processing the request for page /bar that the anchor #tos exists so that I can show the terms of service

The only thing I could think of is to dump the request object and look in there hoping it was in path_in, query_string or something else, but it wasn't. Otherwise, I really don't know where to look.

I know, internal links are for linking inside of a page and if I need page /foo to tell page /bar to do something, I should use parameters and not internal link. However, my client wants the hash link, #tos, for seo reasons so I am trying to find a solution for them. Any help?

Comment: what kind of seo deals with hashes in hrefs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to address this with JavaScript most likely.  You should be able to do something like:

```
if(window.location.hash == '#tos'){
    showTos();
}
```

Comment: fair enough. I was hoping for a server side solution, but this will work. Thanks for your response.